# Can I load jQuery in Foundation Zurb Framework from google CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, web-frameworks

Can I load jQuery in fondation from google CDN, I know of the:

```
 `<script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script>`
```

and its loaded from the server that is hosting the side. Do I just include google CDN in the header and leave it like that or can I remove jquery from local directories(how to change the ternary operator, I mean in what way?)

Comment: Sorry Im was meaning Foundation ZURB Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it to load jQuery from Google CDN and Zepto from your server:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

You can also make it always load jQuery and completely ignore Zepto, to do this add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your `<head>` section and remove `document.write` call.

Comment: Thank you jsut what I needed to know.